# How do you iterate over BS4 elements that has the same name?

Tags: python, loops, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

It only scrapes the first table and I'm not sure on how to get it to scrape the second, they both have the same class.

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

def getData(url):
    r = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
```

Answer (score 1):

Your question is misleading, there is no second `table` on this page, there is only the option to load more data.

Unless you want to switch to `selenium`, you can also address the resource from which the data is dynamically reloaded.

```
for p in range(1,3,1):
    getCalendarData(f'https://www.motorsport.com/all/schedule/2022/upcoming/?all_event_types=1&p={p}')
```

##### Example

A bit more generic with `while-loop`, to check if there is a *load more* button:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url = 'https://www.motorsport.com/all/schedule/2022/upcoming/'

def getCalendarData(table):
        for  event in table.find_all('tbody'):
            Series = event.find('div',class_ = 'ms-schedule-table-item-main__title').text.strip()
            Circuit = event.find('div',class_ = 'ms-schedule-table-item-main__event').text.strip()
            Month = event.find('span',class_ = 'ms-schedule-table-date__month').text.strip()
            Day = event.find('span',class_ = 'ms-schedule-table-date__day').text.strip()  
            print(Series,Circuit,Month,Day)
while True:
    print(f'Scraping url: {url}')
    r = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
    getCalendarData(soup.find('table',class_ = 'ms-schedule-table ms-schedule-table--your'))

    if soup.select_one('[data-id="nextPage"]'):
        url = 'https://www.motorsport.com/'+soup.select_one('[data-id="nextPage"]').get('href')
    else:
        break
```

Comment: Sorry for this misleading question, after posting this I realised that it was the load more button that was the issue. Thank you for the code this is so useful and has solved the issue I was having. Very grateful.